# Angular: How to make whole table row clickable within ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="star in stars">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="/#/stars/{{star.id}}">{{star.id}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{star.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It renders entities. So far the first column is clickable. I want to make the whole table row (`<tr>`) clickable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

You can place `ng-click` inside of your `<tr>` and then have a function in your controller that redirects to the correct URL. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-click="goToLink(star)">
        <td>{{star.id}}</td>
        <td>{{star.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.goToLink = function(star) {
  $location.path('#/stars/' + star.id);
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good workaround. But I heard that it is better to create a directive for  such purpose. WDYT, Hunter?

Comment: In my opinion, it kind of just depends on how you want your code to be structured. There really is no difference if both are added to the `$scope`.